# Hello, Site not being responsive on mobile device but is on desktop. What have I done?

Tags: css, media-queries, screen, responsive

Ive just uploaded my first site for testing and already found that on a mobile device it isnt doing what I wanted? sorry this is my first site and first question so if you need any more information please ask. The site is nixoncreations.com . The images in desktop should be in a row of 3 , ive added

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .portfolio-items-wrapper {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr ;}
```

It works on my laptop screen but not my phone, any advice and help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 
  ##Device = Desktops
  ##Screen = 1281px to higher resolution desktops
*/

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  
  /* CSS */
  
}

/* 
  ##Device = Laptops, Desktops
  ##Screen = B/w 1025px to 1280px
*/

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  
  /* CSS */
  
}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  
  /* CSS */
  
}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  
  /* CSS */
  
}

/* 
  ##Device = Low Resolution Tablets, Mobiles (Landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 481px to 767px
*/

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  
  /* CSS */
  
}

/* 
  ##Device = Most of the Smartphones Mobiles (Portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 320px to 479px
*/

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  
  /* CSS */
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that I will use that in the future, still didnt work but I found out what it was. I forgot to add this, as I said I'm new and would love advice

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```